# How do I get the text game to start?

Tags: python

I'm new to code. I'm currently working on the final project for my very first class. We're supposed to make a text based game. I'm trying to make a horror game and I'm wanting the rooms and items to be decribed as the player comes across them in order for the story to be told. I've got a working code (I think), but I can't actually get the game to start so that the player can begin typing in inputs.

Edit: I've removed the indent in the "print()" line under the "while true" loop, but I'm still stuck on the main menu. The game isn't describing the current room or pompting me to put in any inputs.

This is the full code to my game:

```py
def main_menu():
    print("You have been wandering the abandoned town for a few days now. There hasn't been "
          "much else to do since the world ended.")
    print("You come across the house while trekking a back-wood neighborhood.")
    print("It looks a lot nicer than the other houses. Less debilitated.")
    print("You decide it looks like a good place to explore, even if it looking at it for too "
          "long leaves you with an odd feeling.")
    print("You enter the Front Yard.")
    print()
    print("Welcome to The House. Collect seven items and enter the Final Room.")
    print("To move, type 'forward,', 'back,' 'left,' or 'right'.")
    print("To pick up an item, type 'yes' or 'no'.")
    print("To exit the game, type 'quit'.")

def iventory():
    items = {
        "Front Entrance Key" : {"name" : "Front Entrance Key", "description" : "An antique, rusted key."},
        "Cutting Knife" : {"name" : "Cutting Knife", "description" : "A large knife used to cleave meat."},
        "Attic Key" : {"name" : "Attic Key", "description" : "A small, silver key."},
        "Family Photo" : {"name" : "Family Photo", "description" : "A photo depicting a small family; a man with glasses, a dark-haired woman, and "
                          "a young girl with curly, brunette hair."},
        "Emily's Journal" : {"name" : "Emily's Journal", "description" : "A journal belonging to the young girl seen in the family photos."
                             "Reading it depicts a sickly, yet cheerful girl slowly growing "
                             "weary and fearful of her father's insistence on constantly taking "
                             "unknown shots she doesn't recall her doctor prescribing, as well "
                             "as her parents sudden bouts of fighting."},
        "Data Journal" : {"name" : "Data Journal", "description" : "A log book kept by Emily's father. Reading the entries depicts a man "
                          "so desperate to save his daughter that he was willing to subject "
                          "both people and animals to strange and painful experiments. He appeared "
                          "triumphant toward the end, though the handwriting's deterioration "
                          "shows his odd mental state."},
        "Apocalyptic Newspaper" : {"name" : "Apocalyptic Newspaper", "description" : "A newspaper published around the time the world ended. It blames a "
                                   "man's cancer treatments for the sudden bouts of uncontrollable violence "
                                   "displayed by the patients."}
    }
    

def house():
    rooms = {
        "Front Yard" : {"name" : "Front Yard", "right" : "Back Yard", "forward": "Front Entrance",
                        "text" : "You have entered the Front Yard. In front of you is the house, quaint and quiet."
                                 "It has a porch and an antique-looking front entrance. To the right, there is "
                                 "the fence that separates the back yard from the front."},
        "Back Yard" : {"name" : "Back Yard", "left" : "Front Yard", "item" : "Front Entrance Key",
                       "text" : "You are in the back yard. It looks much worse back here, with an old, debilitated shed "
                                "and a broken down truck. It's paint is so rusted and peeled, it almost appears pink."
                                "The inside is clean, if old and worn down. The console is unlocked. You look inside."},
        "Front Entrance" : {"name" : "Front Entrance", "back" : "Front Yard", "right" : "Kitchen",
                            "left" : "Living Room", "forward" : "Upstairs Hallway",
                            "text" : "Walking through the Front Entrance, you are greeted with a modest home. In front "
                                     "of you is a set of stairs, to the right the kitchen, and to the left the living "
                                     "room."},
        "Kitchen" : {"name" : "Kitchen", "left": "Front Entrance", "item": "Cutting Knife",
                     "text": "The kitchen is a mess. Food is left on the table as if the family wasn't expecting to leave."
                             "The fridge is rusted and some of the cabinets are torn open. One the counter, there is a "
                             "knife block filled with cutlery."},
        "Living Room" : {"name" : "Living Room", "right" : "Front Entrance", "forward" : "Downstairs Bathroom",
                         "item" : "Family Photo",
                         "text" : "The living room is small, with an old school box TV in the corner and a couch and chair "
                                  "facing it. Forward, there is a small hallway leading to a bathroom, decorated with "
                                  "photographs."},
        "Downstairs Bathroom" : {"name" : "Downstairs Bathroom", "back" : "Living Room", "item" : "Attic Key",
                                 "text" : "The bathroom is tiny, only a half-bath as opposed to a full. Something glints "
                                          "in the rusted sink."},
        "Upstairs Hallway" : {"name" : "Upstairs Hallway", "back" : "Front Entrance", "left" : "Emily's Room",
                              "right" : "Upstairs Bathroom", "forward" : "Hallway End",
                              "text" : "Upstairs is only a long hallway. To the left, a door decorated with a young girl's drawing."
                              "To the right, an open door leading to another bathroom. Further down, you can see more "
                              "doors."},
        "Emily's Room" : {"name" : "Emily's Room", "right" : "Upstairs Hallway", "item" : "Emily's Journal",
                          "text" : "Inside the girl's room, the far wall is decorated with letters spelling out the name "
                                   "Emily. The room is small and filled with toys, drawings, and crayons. The bed is "
                                   "plain, small with a purple cover. The corner of a book peaks out from beneath the blanket."},
        "Upstairs Bathroom" : {"name" : "Upstairs Bathroom", "left" : "Upstairs Hallway",
                               "text" : "The bathroom is surprisingly large. You are taken aback by the sight of rusted, "
                                        "browned blood splattered across the mirror. You risk peaking behind the curtain of "
                                        "the shower-tub. The body of the mother from the photograph lies limply inside, a "
                                        "gaping wound on her head. It stinks. She is rotten. She's been here a while."
                                        "You don't want to be in this room anymore."},
        "Hallway End" : {"name" : "Hallway End", "back" : "Upstairs Hallway", "left" : "Strange Couple's Room",
                         "forward" : "Attic",
                         "text" : "Walking further down the hallway brings you next to the open ladder leading to the attic."
                                  "To the left is another door."},
        "Strange Couple's Room" : {"name" : "Strange Couple's Room", "right" : "Hallway End", "item": "Data Journal",
                                   "text" : "The room clearly belongs to Emily's parents. It is quaint, with a well-made bed and "
                                            "a large office desk to the far right. An open journal sits atop the desk."},
        "Attic" : {"name" : "Attic", "back" : "Hallway End", "forward" : "Strange Room", "item" : "Apocalyptic Newspaper",
                   "text" : "As you climb the ladder to the attic, you can't help but feel repulsed. The sight in front of "
                            "you is clearly the workspace of the strange man with glasses. Emily's father. You would think it "
                            "was a morgue with the way the tables of covered bodies line up. There is a chem desk in the corner "
                            "and an oddly reinforced door at the end of the room. You see some strewn papers as you pass by the "
                            "chem desk."},
        "Strange Room" : {"name" : "Strange Room", "text" : "Something in you dreads entering the room, but your curiosity "
                                                            "gets the better of you. Inside is nothing but a small, medical bed. "
                                                            "Clearly, this is where Emily was forced to stay while her father "
                                                            "tried creating her medicine. There is a mutilated body on the floor."
                                                            "Emily's father. You're nearly not fast enough to notice Emily as she lunges for you."}
        }

directions = ['forward', 'back', 'right', 'left']
pick_up_item = ['yes']
main_menu()
current_room = "Front Yard"

while True:
    if current_room == "Strange Room":
        if len(inventory) == 7:
            print("Luckily, you discovered all of the strange items within the house, learned Emily's history as patient"
                  "zero. You even found a large knife. You use it to defend yourself, swiping at Emily and distracting her"
                  "long enough to sprint from the room. You run and you don't look back.")
            print("Good End")

        else:
            print("Unfortunately, you have not discovered all of the items within the house. You do not have the means to "
                  "defend yourself from Emily as she closes in on you. She drags you further into the room.")
            print("Bad End")
print("You are in {}.".format(current_room["name"]["text"]))
pick_up_item = input('\nDo you wish to inspect the item? ')
command = input('\nWhat do you do? ')
if command in directions:
    if command in current_room:
        current_room = rooms[current_room[command]]
    else:
        print('You cannot go that way.')
elif command == 'quit':
    print('Thanks for playing!')
else:
    print('Invalid input')
```

Comment: Basically, I'm stuck on the main_menu.

Comment: Did you mean to indent the last 12 lines so that they are under the `while True:` block? Currently it looks like your program gets stuck in there.

Comment: So, should I move them? Do I remove the space between them or do I indent them so they are more under the start of the 'if' line?

Comment: I removed the indent, but I'm still stuck on the main menu. It's not describing the current room or prompting me to put my input in.

Comment: We have answered the question of why is your program stuck. Changes to improve the situation only lead to python discovering your other errors. (richard's answer indicates this). You can ask a brand new question with the 'fixed' code if you supply the error traceback.

Answer (score 1):

You are stuck in the `while True` loop. To start you need to include the lines starting with `print("You are in {}...` at the same indentation as the lines in the `while` loop. There will be some other issues to fix after that.

Comment: So I need to move the 'print("You are in)' or it should stay on the same line as the 'while'? What other issues do I have by the way? I'm trying to clean it up, but I'm just not sure where to start.

Comment: I removed the indent, but I'm still stuck on the main menu. It's not describing the current room or prompting me to put my input in.

Comment: `print("You are in {}...` and below needs to be at the same indentation as `if current_room...`.  the dictionaries `items` and `rooms` are inside functions for no reason. read up on [Python Scope](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp) and you will see that you will problems with your code running.

Comment: When I move it to under the if current_room line, it errors out

Comment: because `current_room` is just a text string and you are trying to use it like a dictionary with `current_room["name"]["text"]`.

Comment: I'm not trying to be rude, but you're not really giving me a lot of details. I said I'm new, this is my very first class. I need help. You're telling me what I'm doing wrong, but you're not really going out of you way to offer a correction or a suggestion beyond reading python scope. How should I properly write it so that it will describe the current room the player is in?

Comment: How do I get the game to actually start intead of just staying on the main menu?

Comment: Here are some fixes to get you playing: [https://onlinegdb.com/MlhYkiMIa](https://onlinegdb.com/MlhYkiMIa)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal version where there are three rooms and a key. If you pick up the key and enter the final room with it in your inventory, then you win. You may be able to modify this for your purposes, if you have any questions about how it works please let me know. My advice though, just break it down line by line, imo sometimes schools have a tendency to either go way too fast or way too slow when teaching programming. YouTube is a really excellent resource for learning programming as long as you take lots of notes. Good luck on your Python journey!

```py
def main_menu():
    print("Welcome to The Game. Find the key and enter the Final Room.")
    print("To move, type 'forward', 'back', 'left', or 'right'.")
    print("To pick up an item, type 'yes' or 'y'.")
    print("To exit the game, type 'quit'.")

def inventory():
    items = {
        "Key" : {"name" : "Key", "description":\
                 "Check out this neat key. I found it in the middle room."}
    }
    return items

def game_map():
    rooms = {
        "Front Room" : {"name" : "Front Room", "forward": "Middle Room"},
        "Middle Room" : {"name" : "Middle Room", "back": "Front Room", "forward": "Final Room", "item": "Key"},
        "Final Room" : {"name" : "Final Room", "back": "Middle Room"}
    }
    return rooms

directions = ['forward', 'back', 'right', 'left']
main_menu()
rooms = game_map()
items = inventory()
current_room = rooms["Front Room"]
player_inventory = []

while True:
    print("You are in {}.".format(current_room["name"]))
    if "item" in current_room and current_room["item"] not in player_inventory:
        pick_up_item = input('\nThere is an item here. Do you wish to pick it up? ')
        if pick_up_item.lower() in ('yes', 'y'):
            player_inventory.append(current_room["item"])
            print("You picked up a {}".format(current_room["item"]))
            print(items[current_room["item"]]["description"])
    if 'Key' in player_inventory and current_room["name"] == "Final Room":
        print("You win!! Hooray!")
        print("Thanks for playing!")
        break
    else:
        command = input('\nWhat do you do? ')
    if command in directions:
        if command in current_room:
            current_room = rooms[current_room[command]]
        else:
            print('You cannot go that way.')
    elif command == 'quit':
        print('Thanks for playing!')
        break
    else:
        print('Invalid input')
```